# How do I keep an object the same under certain conditions in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

For my job, I am creating a shiny app.  It works fine at the moment, but getting the data requires me to interface with SQL, which takes a while.  This app uses the data in two ways: 1) to display the data, 2) to use the data to run a simulation (which is also time consuming).  I need to be able to get data for a number of different customers.

So far I can get the data separate from simulation, and use the data I already have directly in simulation, provided I have the right data already.  If the customer number changes, I can get the data, and run simulation.  All of these things are great, but the one thing I cannot do is display the data I get for simulation if I did not already have the right data.

I have tried several methods to accomplish this, but the one I am currently working on is attempting to have the data object remain the same as it was if I already have the data, and the customer number is correct, but change under all other circumstances.  All the methods I have tried to do this either give me an infinite loop, or a blank data set.  I have created a dumbed down version of the app (because I cannot display the real one) that should highlight the problem I am having.  This is what I currently have:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(wellPanel(
    #create at action button to generate data.
    actionButton("gen", "Generate"),
    textOutput("check")
    ),
    wellPanel(
      #'create an action button for simulation.  Here there is no simulation because
      #'I am not having a problem with simulation, but this should also generate
      #'data if there is no data, or the customer numbers do not match
      actionButton("sim", "Simulate"),
      #indicates whether the customer numbers match
      checkboxInput("same", "Same customer number", value = T),
      #output the data table
      dataTableOutput("data")
      ))
  ))

library(mvtnorm)


shinyServer(function(input, output){
  #'every time I hit the sim button, this is set as the gen button's count.
  #'By checking to see if this equals the count of the gen button, I can generate
  #'data every time I hit the gen button, but not every time I hit the sim button
  gen.check<-reactive({
    input$sim
    isolate({as.numeric(input$gen)})
  })
  output$check<-renderText({
    gen.check()<input$gen
  })
  #indicates whether there is already data or not
  check<-reactive({
    if(input$gen==0 & input$sim==0){
      FALSE
    }else{
      TRUE
    }
  })
  #generate the data
  data<-reactive({
    #'this stops the app from displaying data when it opens.  Not super important
    #'here, but in the actual app, getting the data is time consuming, so I don't
    #'want it to start out by getting data I don't need
    if(input$gen==0 & input$sim==0){
      return()
    }
    #This line makes data show up every time I hit the gen button
    if(input$gen>gen.check()){
      rmvnorm(20, 1:5, diag(5))
    }else{
      #'I had hoped this blank loop here would make the data stay the same if there
      #'already was data, and the customer numbers matched, but instead it makes the
      #'data disappear under these conditions
      if(isolate({input$same}) & check()){
      }else{
        #'This generates data if there is none, or if the numbers don't match when
        #'you hit sim
        rmvnorm(200, 1:5, diag(rep(.1, 5)))
      }
    }
  })
  #'This piece is separate because in the actual app I need to use the data generated
  #'above two different ways.  I am just using it here to check when the data changes.
  output$data<-renderDataTable({
    if(input$gen==0 & input$sim==0){
      return()
    }
    as.data.frame(data())
  })
})
```

When I click the "gen" button, the code successfully generates data.  It also generates and displays data when I click the "sim" button, if the checkbox indicates the numbers are not the same.  I was hoping that if I had already generated data, and I clicked simulate, that nothing would happen to the data I was displaying if the customer numbers are the same.

The data() that I am directly displaying here would be used the same way in the app I am creating for work (although it would be real data, not generated data), and the same data() goes directly to the simulation.  Getting this to change, but only when appropriate, is the only problem I am having.

edit:  This is my first time asking a question, so I am sure I have formatted this poorly.  If it is still unclear, please try to let me know where I am losing you.

edit: the memoise package was able to accomplish the task.  For example, if my data grabbing function was data.grab(customer_no), and needed to interface with SQL, then before my app, I included

```
grabber<-memoise(data.grab)
```

Then I replaced all instances of data.grab with grabber.  This made it so if I use the same customer I have previously used, it uses the results from the last time I ran the function with those parameters instead of interfacing with SQL again.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow. Could you please edit it add how the sample code should work, and how it is failing. Such as  "When you click the Simulate button X should happen but Y does instead" or whatever. Thanks.

Comment: As @John Paul says, it's really a bit difficult to understand.If I get it right, your problem can be handled by some sort of caching. I have successfully used package `memoise` in Shiny to handle this efficiently.

Comment: Dear @Unimportant, the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: Oh My God.  @DieterMenne, I just used memoise and it works so much better than I had hoped for.  A much better solution than what I was even trying to do.

Comment: To avoid your question being closed, as a help for others and as a memo to yourself, it would be good if you could post a self-contained example using `memoise`. Answering your own questions is welcome here. You may even get some credit for doing so.

Comment: @DieterMenne The code I posted above doesn't really apply to memoise, or at least it is very strange to have a random function always return the same value.  In fact, memoise does not do what I wanted that app to be able to do.  I would post the app that uses memoise, but I imagine my boss would consider most of the contents of the app (not including the memoise part) to be proprietary secrets.  I will try to give an example of how it worked though.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was unclear. Posting an example how it worked is the method of choice, and feel free to rename your variables if these should reveal some proprietary stuff.